# Stuck with sigwait

Tags: c, macos, signals

I did something wrong in my code, where an other process send a SIGUSR2 signal to it:

```
sigset_t sigset;
sigemptyset(&sigset);
sigaddset(&sigset, SIGILL);
sigaddset(&sigset, SIGUSR2);
sigwait(&sigset, &received);
```

XCode notices SIGUSER2(31) signal received, but received = SIGILL(4) (or the minimal signal in the set).

Why is that so? Where I am wrong?

Now, it looks like this:

```
    sigset_t sigset;
    sigemptyset(&sigset);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGILL);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGUSR2);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, 0);
    sigwait(&sigset, &received);
    if(received == SIGUSR2) {
        //...
    } else if(received == SIGILL) {
        //...
    }
```

Still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the debugger can get in the way. I have seen debuggers interfere with signal handling before. Try running the code without the debugger involved.

The following code works perfectly on OS X:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    sigset_t set;
    int sig;

    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR2);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
    sigwait(&set, &sig);
    printf("Got signal %d\n", sig);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user408141: Does my code work for you? What output do you get if you build it, run it and kill -USR2 it?

Comment: @user408141: Also, do not run the program in the debugger. I have seen debugger and signals not work together well in the past. The debugger may be the problem.

Comment: Yeah, debug mode was the faulty :) Thx.
[Me noob :P]

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the related question [sigwait in Linux (Fedora 13) vs OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963283/sigwait-in-linux-fedora-13-vs-os-x), you need to block the signal using `sigprocmask()` (for single-threaded applications) or `pthread_sigmask()` (for multi-threaded applications).

Checking `sigwait`'s return value for errors would not be bad either.

Comment: I tried it, but with no success. I added a new line:
sigset_t sigset;
            sigemptyset(&sigset);
            sigaddset(&sigset, SIGILL);
            sigaddset(&sigset, SIGUSR2);
            sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, 0);
            sigwait(&sigset, &received);

Still worng.

Comment: I have checked it, it returns 0.